# Jquery "find" problem

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help with a problem with a JQuery Find?
In the example below I want to find the select & text objects within Div1. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="div1" style="border:solid 1px #c6c8dd; background-color:#ff0000; padding:5px;">
 <div style="width:916px; padding-top:10px;">
  <select id="Select1" runat="server"></select>&nbsp:
  <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width:200px;" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
Select1 = jQuery("#div1").find("#Select1")[0];
Text1 = jQuery("#div1").find("#Text1")[0];
```

Select1 comes back as undefined, but it finds the Text1 object.

Can anyone tell me why I can't find the Select1 object?

Comment: Why don't you just do `jQuery('#Select1')`? And if you tell me that you have several elements with the same ID, I'll tell you that this is not valid and you should use classes instead :) And if your code is correctly placed in the `ready` handler, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/cdT7X/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rkMuZ/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get the selected value.. use this method instead

$("#div1 select[name$='name-of-your-select']") will return the object and adding .val() on the end will get you the selected value

Answer (score 0):

```
Select1 = $("#Select1");
Text1 = $("#Text1");
```